# How to Include Variables in a File Name used in a Variable $File Equals

Tags: ksh, aix

Why does the echo not return - /lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_1_vmobius_05122021.txt ?
It returns --> the $FILE

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
integer max=3
integer i=1
while [[ $i -lt $max ]]
do
today=`date +%m%d%Y`
FILE = "/lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_$i_vmobius_$today.txt"
echo "the $FILE"

echo $i
echo "the $FILE"
(( i = i + 1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ${...} around variables for interpolation inside string literals - it makes things clearer and helps the interpreter.

Indentation helps readability and maintainability.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
integer max=3
integer i=1 
while (( i < max ))
do
    today=`date +%m%d%Y`
    FILE="/lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_${i}_vmobius_${today}.txt"
    echo "the $FILE"
    echo $i
    echo "the $FILE"
    (( i ++ ))
done
```

Comment: the date works great - but not populating the $i  - its returning as --> the /lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_05122021.txt